# Browser-side client for Hyperledger Fabric 1.0?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hyperledger Fabric has various SDKs  (Node, Java, Go etc...) which are used to communicate with the fabric. A web user who wants to make a transaction must call a server that hosts a client based on those SDKs, which will then pass the call to the fabric.

I would like to skip a step and have a web browser application which submits transactions to a peer in the fabric. In v0.6 we developed a web app that made REST calls directly to the nodes but the API had security problems and is now deprecated.

If that's not possible, could someone explain to me why having a server for web users requests does not make the whole system more centralized?

Is developing with the Node SDK and then using Browserify a viable solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really an appropriate question for SO, but there is an active proposal for a fabric-sdk-rest sub-project being considered by the maintainers.

Comment: Did you make any findings that you could share? What has been your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric API is in GRPC, so you would have to find the right package to support GRPC in browsers.